# Width for link button works outside a div menu, but not inside?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, width

Please observe this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8nrPm/3/

I have set the width of the *Animation* button by adding this:

```
.manimation a{
    width: 360px;text-align:center;border-bottom:9px solid #43cf61
}
```

Works fine. Now, hover your mouse over the ***MORE*** button, there is two buttons there and using the same technique to set width does not have any effect for those buttons.

As you can see in my stylesheet, I have set width for the *Games* button by adding this:

```
.mgames a{
    width: 150px;text-align:center;font-style:normal;border-bottom:9px solid #e34328
}
```

But the width has no effect. **Why? How do I set the width for it?**

I would advice overlooking the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8nrPm/3/ as I am sure there must be something that is preventing the width from working. Also, I tried to add the `!important` to it but did not work.

Comment: would you provide the image you want to get

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand what you mean there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**anchor** is an `inline` element. An inline element is not take `width, height, vertical margin & padding`. Write like this:

```
.megadiv a{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I read up about it quickly and it appears to be the issue, however, when I added the **display:block;** to the **megadiv a** it completely changed the layout of the *MORE* button, including the buttons inside it, why? Please have a look at this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8nrPm/4/

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that that styling was in the Li. So thank you for this, I have upvoted and accepted this answer!